# REST API does not respond

Tags: rest-api

Let's say a have

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Test/v1')
global with sharing class MuleTest {
    @HttpGet
    global static Contact getAccountContacts() {
        RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
        String accId = request.requestURI.substring(request.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        system.debug(accId);
        return [select id,
                        firstName, 
                        LastName 
                from Contact where Account.id= :accId];
    }

}
```

Then I'm trying to revoke this from POSTMAN
uri: https://mule-test-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Test/v1/getAccountContacts

I've set up security token header and username/pass for basic auth.
But I get an error

> Could not get any response
>   There was an error connecting to https://mule-test-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Test/v1/getAccountContacts.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: SF does not support HTTP Basic Auth, you have to use [oAuth](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_oauth_and_connected_apps.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your `@RestResource` annotation and the URL you're using in order for this to work.

The body of your method is looking for the Account Id as the last part of the URL but it isn't defined in your mapping and your URL doesn't provide it.

You should update your annotation to `@RestResource(urlMapping='/Test/v1/*')` and then your URL to `https://mule-test-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Test/v1/ACCOUNTID` and pass in an actual account id for `ACCOUNTID`.

There's a very [similar example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_code_sample_restrequest.htm) in the documentation for reference.

Comment: How can I get a sessionId for bearer?

Comment: For testing you can just use the username-password OAuth flow (example at the bottom of this page: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm)